# Use named URLs in @login_required decorator

Tags: django

I am using a custom URL for my login page. Django's `@login_required` decorator however takes me to `accounts/login`.

I saw that the 3rd param of this decorator is the URL to which you're taken if not logged in. Now I want to pass a value from my urls.py to this decorator:

```
@login_required(login_url=myapp.urls.my_url_name)
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but is there some alternative syntax which lets me achieve this? Alternatively, is there a global variable, which I can set only once, and which overrides the `login_url` param?

Comment: did you try `@login_required(login_url=reverse('myapp.urls.my_url_name'))` ?

Comment: @karthikr suspect that would cause a circular dependency as it has to be resolved at import time. `reverse_lazy` might work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the URL users not logged in will be redirected to by setting `LOGIN_URL` in your `settings.py` globally. (Of course you can also override that setting where ever you apply the decorator if you want to.)

According to the docs, you can also specify named url patterns, e.g., `LOGIN_URL = 'myapp:login'`, and view function names, e.g., `LOGIN_URL = 'myapp.login_view'`.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url):

> **LOGIN_URL**
>
> Default: `'/accounts/login/'`
>
> The URL where requests are redirected for login, especially when using the `login_required()` decorator.
>
> This setting also accepts view function names and named URL patterns which can be used to reduce configuration duplication since you don’t have to define the URL in two places (settings and URLconf).

For reference:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Comment: This is what I ended up doing (the view function names part). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the login URL of your site in your settings.py file as LOGIN_URL. Then, you don't have to worry about changing it in the different places.